# No such file or directory - file is present

Tags: bash, ubuntu-mate

`enter code here`I do not understand why I am getting the "No such file..." error.

fstab is in home/andy/Downloads/

Here is what is relevant in my backup script.

```
# Backup fstab
cat /etc/fstab > home/andy/Downloads/fstab
tar -cvf fstab.tar home/andy/Downloads/fstab
rsync --progress -r -u fstab.tar $Backup_Directory
rsync --progress -r -u fstab.tar $Local_Backup_Dir
```

And the output.

```
Thunar_Settings.tar
10,240 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1) sending incremental file list
-rw-rw-r--         10,240 2022/12/01 22:27:27 Thunar_Settings.tar
/home/andy/bin/Backup_20_04.sh: line 79: home/andy/Downloads/fstab: No such file or directory
tar: home/andy/Downloads/fstab: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

I added the / to the appropriate places.

tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/home/andy/Downloads/fstab
sending incremental file list
fstab.tar

It creates the tar file and sends it to the 2 locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script uses the absolute path `home/andy...` but this is not a valid path.

Absolute paths must start with a `/`

So if your username is `andy` then the absolute path to your user's home folder would be `/home/andy/...`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I made the changes you suggested. And results are in my original post.